# How to transfer data as a single object from one GUI to another?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, data-transfer-objects

We need to transfer multiple data objects like `String`, `int`, `float`, etc from one GUI (`JFrame`, `JInternalFrame`, etc) to another GUI. We can tranfer them by using parameters in the constructors or share the data through a singleton class.

However, my question is how to pack multiple data objects into a single object and pass them as a single parameter between GUIs in Java Swing? In Android, we can do that using Bundle objects. Similarly, is there any such object in Java/Swing which can be used?

Comment: May I know exactly what type  of data do you want to transfer?

Comment: `List<Object>` springs to mind.. BTW - it is singular with an upper case letter - 'Swing', not lower case plural 'swings'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous options, however the two most likely to meet your needs would either be a custom `Object` or a `Map`. A custom object would have fields for each piece of information you need to transfer. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) for more information.